# How to load a module in Python 3 when there is a package with the same name?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, python-3.5

When working on some legacy Python package, I noticed there was a sub-package *shadowing* a module with the same name. Here is a simplified file hierarchy showing the problem:

```
t/
t/__init__.py
t/u/
t/u.py
t/u/__init__.py
```

As you can see, there is a python module `t/u.py` and also a sub-package `t/u/` It looks like a standard `import` statement loads the sub-package:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Oct  8 2019, 13:06:37) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import t.u
__init__.py
>>>
```

But, is there a way to import the module `t/u.py` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe *from t import u* and *from t.u import u* works